# Efficiency of UDP protocol

Tags: computer-networks

When 54 bytes of data is transferred using the UDP protocol, the efficiency is? (In per cent)

IN UDP, the maximum datagram size can be $2^{16}-1 \, bytes$

Now to this, 8 Bytes of UDP header is included and this together must fit within $65535\, bytes$ IPv4 packet limit(Including 20B IP Header size).

So, maximum data that we can send in 1 UDP datagram-> $65535-8-20=65507\,Bytes$

We could have sent this amount of data, but we are actually sending 54 Bytes, so the efficiency of the protocol is $\frac{54}{65507} \times 100(\,in\,\%)$

Am I correct?

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: But the answer is "no". It is absurd. If the packet limit was 4 gigabyte, why would that affect the efficiency of sending a small block?

Answer (score 1):

We are not sending a full packet, so there is no need to consider the maximum size of a packet when calculating. The efficiency is usually expressed as the ratio of the "data we want to send" to all the data being sent, which in your case would give:

effieciency = (54/(54+28))*100% ~ 66%

We would have to consider the maximum size of the packet when calculating the maximum efficiency of a UDP protocol, which describes a case scenario where a full packet is sent.